# Add a cooldown that stops a user from using a command

Tags: python, discord, python-3.6, discord.py

I'm trying to add a sort of cooldown for a health system to my bot. So that once a member's health hits zero, they're not able to run a command until one hour after they've hit 0. I had seen `@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)` when researching possible solutions but I didn't think it would really work here since the cooldown isn't on the actual command itself. Here's my first attempt at trying to add a cooldown (was trying to get it working before cleaning it up so sorry about that)

```py
def start_cooldown(ctx): # is called after the bot detects the user hits 0 hp or less
  stopTime=str(datetime.now().time()) # gets current time
  hours=stopTime[0:2]; minutes=stopTime[3:5] # separates hours from mins
  if hours[0] == '0': # removes the first zero (honestly not sure if I need this)
    hours[0]=''
  if hours=='00': # converts 00 to 24 (midnight to 24 hours)
    hours='24'
  global on_cooldown
  on_cooldown.update({ctx.author.id:f'{hours} {minutes}'}) # dictionary that contains members' ids and their cooldowns (if they have one)
  print(f'on_cooldown={on_cooldown}')

def check_cooldown(ctx): # called at the start of the command
  currentTime=str(datetime.now().time())
  hours=currentTime[0:2]; minutes=currentTime[3:5]
  print(hours,minutes)
  if hours[0] == '0':
    hours[0]=''
  if hours=='00':
    hours='24' # all the same as above
  print(hours,minutes)
  #cooldown ends at '24 50' 12:50am
  #current time is  '23 50' 11:50pm
  while True: # tries to get the member's cooldown, if a KeyError is raised (the member has no active cooldown), then the function ends and returns nothing (the command continues to run)
    try:
      cooldownEnd=on_cooldown[ctx.author.id] 
      break
    except KeyError:
      return

    print(f'[Line 71]\nhours={hours}\ncooldownEnd={cooldownEnd[0:2]}\nminutes={minutes}\ncooldownEnd[3:]={cooldownEnd[3:]}')

    if int(hours) > int(cooldownEnd[0:2]) and int(minutes) >= int(cooldownEnd[3:]):
      on_cooldown.pop(ctx.author.id) # checks if the current time is past the time the cooldown was started

    if on_cooldown[ctx.author.id] in on_cooldown:
      timeRemaining=int(cooldownEnd[3:]) - int(minutes)
      return(f'Sorry! You\'re still resting, try again in {timeRemaining} minutes.')
```

Comment: Your code to get hours by going from datetime to a time and then parsing that is a bit mad, because datetime already has friendly members that give you hours, minutes etc directly: import datetime; now = datetime.datetime.now(); now.hour #is 23

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The idea to use a dictionary that maps users to times is good, but the syntax for updating the dict is convoluted. I'd do just: on_cooldown[ctx.author.id] = now . Then check the nice comparison functions that datetime objects have for calculation durations etc.

Comment: @Steve I was wondering if anyone had ideas on how to implement a sort of cool down system that would start a one hour timer starting at the point where a member's hp = 0. And during that one hour period, it would stop them from running a command, although someone else may have provided a fix

Comment: @antont Thanks, I actually ended up finding a different fix for it when searching for something else and found a command that can get the time from an amount time from either before/after the current time